# Is it better to use soft or hard ladyfingers when making tiramisu?

Tags: cake

I didn't realize they came in two varieties.

Comment: I hadn't realized there were two kinds either, I make my own and they come out like a stiff but still spongy sponge cake almost. And to be honest, I don't make fingers for tiramisu, I use a finger recipe and make a flat cake out of it. I guess you could them lady cakes. I prefer to do it that way, and ladle my coffee mixture on top of that and let it soak in before spreading my filling over it. Makes for a neater presentation IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always use the hard ones and they contribute to a good end result.

I guess with the soft ones it can end up soggy. The hard ones will absorb the liquids and will get a little softer, so the end result won't break down immediately.